# batch script error checking and write to file

Tags: batch-file, error-logging, standard-error

I am writing a batch script that copies files from one location to another, renames the original files, ftps them then deletes the originals. I have one question of error logging. How do I get an error that encountered in a batch script to exit the script and then write to a log file of my choosing?

SAMPLE ERROR: "ERROR: The system was unable to find..."

Answer (score 0):

By doing something like this:

```
psftp.exe blah blah blah
IF ERRORLEVEL == 1 CALL :LOGANDEXIT "%output%"
...
...
GOTO :END
...
:LOG ARG
ECHO %~1 > out.log
EXIT /B 0
:LOGANDEXIT ARG
ECHO %~1 > err.log
GOTO :END
...
:END
ECHO Done.
pause
```

Comment: Yes, I changed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask in the question comments.

Comment: Of course, my answer is not complete since I don't know fully what you are doing.  You can fill in any blanks by using dostips.com for reference.